# pandas - renaming axis

Tags: python, pandas

I want to rename the the x axis in my pandas dataframe. I have 100 values in the dataframe. Instead of plotting from 0 to 100 at an interval of 1, I want to plot from -2500 to 2500 at every 50 interval.

I have the following code:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(10,figsize=[16,20])

window = int(math.ceil(5000.0 / 100))
xticks = range(-2500,2500,window)

for i,lid in enumerate(x1_top100_lids[:10]):
    if lid in data:
        pd.Series(data[lid]).plot(ax=ax[i],title=lid,time=xticks)
```

However, I just get the error: time not defined.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument time does not exist. Try to go for "pd.Series.plot??" in the command line of IPython to see the doc string. So, try to use xticks=xticks instead.

```
    def __call__(self, kind='line', ax=None,
             figsize=None, use_index=True, title=None, grid=None,
             legend=False, style=None, logx=False, logy=False,
             loglog=False, xticks=None, yticks=None,
             xlim=None, ylim=None,
             rot=None, fontsize=None, colormap=None, table=False,
             yerr=None, xerr=None,
             label=None, secondary_y=False, **kwds):
```